# Fetch div using javascript [NO jQuery]

Tags: javascript, dom

How to access divs inside div.id = "columns" using traditional javascript no jQuery please

```
<div id="columns">
   <div>DiV A</div>
   <div>DiV B</div>
   <div>DiV C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

[Mark Reed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10771475/139010) works in [newer browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector). This will work with pretty much anything:

```
var divs = document.getElementById('columns').getElementsByTagName('div');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var columns = document.querySelectorAll('#columns > div');
```

Comment: Can we do it without "querySelectorAll"... i am looking for different possible ways

Comment: Pay attention to support. It doesnt support IE7 -: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll

Comment: See @MattBall's answer for an even more traditional alternative.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a more hand worked solution (root traditional), you can try this:

```
var col = document.getElementById('columns');
for (var i =0; i < col.childNodes.length; i++) {
    var node = col.childNodes[i];
    if (node.nodeType == 1) {
        // do something with the node here
    }
}
```

Comment: `.childNodes` returns the text nodes with the elements.

Comment: Sure, and you can check the `nodeType` to filter what do you want (1 in case of elements).

Comment: when i say node.length i get 4 but it should 3 i suppose; since we have only 3 divs

Comment: Why would you do this instead of use `getElementsByTagName()`, given the OP's question?

Comment: He asked for a traditional way. I'm not sayng its the best one. I've just presented other way of doing so.

Comment: @Coolenough If you look at the comment just above yours, you will see that I've said to filter the nodes by its `nodeType` property. Anyways, I've edited the answer.